# Sorting a client heartbeat from an actual data return?

Tags: c#, tcp, heartbeat

So in a nutshell, I have server set up using tcplistener / tcpclient, and it has a couple dozen client machines. Everything is working well, except that I do not yet have a system set up to detect whether or not a client has disconnected. I would like to use heartbeats (periodically sent packets) to show the client is still there. Unfortunately, what is happening is that the server has a waiting receive block called so that it can get actual data from the clients, but it is receiving the heartbeats instead. Is there any way I can set up another receive on the same port that is looking specifically for heartbeats? -Thanks.

Comment: Are you able to give us the code of what you've tried so far?

Comment: @peacemaker It's a bit long (over a thousand lines); is there perhaps any aspect of my code you need me to explain (or post here) that would help you answer?

Comment: Just the parts relevant to the question. If that is still too much code, try to create a simple example showing the main issue.

Comment: @peacemaker Hold on, I'll edit in a quick example.

Comment: Specifically, you can show us what the server packet receiving code looks like.  It may be that you can just check the packet type there, and if it's a heartbeat packet, deal with it specifically, otherwise treat it as data.

Comment: @peacemaker Well that's actually the issue I'm having, is finding the right way to set up the packet receiving code. In theory, I could make a variation of your answer work, but with a couple dozen clients each sending a packet every second, I would really prefer not to clog the receiver for my data. putting aside all other factors, I am just using a simple Socket.Receive() to get the incoming data, and I'm not sure how well it would be able to process a hundred incoming sources of data at once. In specific, is there any way I could create a totally separate, threaded receive JUST for packets?

Comment: Sure, you can create many threads, each listening out for a specific packet type and if what they receive isn't that type they just ignore it.  It's fairly straightforward, if you've got this far you'll have no problems with it :)

Comment: @peacemaker Ahhh ok, I think we're on the right track now. Yes: I have this extra thread set up, with its own receive. There is another receive in its own thread for real data though. If data is incoming, it will automatically go to the first Receive that is called, right? Is there a way to make this packet data go specifically to one of the receives, rather than the one called first?

Comment: As far as I'm aware, all sockets that are receiving on the same port will receive the data as it's broadcast.  Therefore, all you need to do is in your data thread, ignore heartbeats and in your heartbeat thread, ignore everything but heartbeats.

Comment: @peacemaker Perfect. This was exactly the answer I was looking for. I clearly had a bad misconception about receives. If you want to edit that into your answer, I'll accept you for good show :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One common way is to define your packets to have a specific type, therefore the server packet receiving code can just check the type and deal with it appropriately.
i.e.

```
if ( packet.type == PacketTypes.HeartBeat )
    //keep alive the client
else
    //it's data (or another packet)
```

When you add your code I can give a better example.

UPDATE:

As per our discussions in the comments, you can simply create a separate thread for dealing with your heartbeat packets.  In this thread, your socket receive code will ignore anything but heartbeat packets by first checking the type.

You can also create another thread housing a socket receive on the same port to deal with your data.  In this case, it would just ignore any heartbeat packets received.